# Setter for Bool in Swift

Tags: swift, setter

I'm using a custom getter like so

```
var currentShowLiked: Bool {
    get {
        return [some condition met] ? true : false
    }
    set {
        self.currentShowLiked = newValue
    }
}
```

and it works fine. However, I would expect to be able to set `true` or `false` value back to my variable, but Swift forced my to implement a setter, which does not produce any warnings, but at runtime if I'm to change value of my variable, app crashes with no apparent reason or sane explanation pointing to setter line with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2...)` and a message in console `warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.`

Why do I do?

Comment: you setter just call itself. and `[some condition met] ? true : false` is identical to `[some condition met]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are in recursive context.

You can't use currentShowLiked in the currentShowLiked property body as below:

```
// Recursive, Infinite loop
self.currentShowLiked = newValue
```

To fix this:

```
private var _currentShowLiked : Bool

var currentShowLiked: Bool {
    get {
        return [ some condition met on _currentShowLiked ] ? true : false
    }
    set {
        self._currentShowLiked = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: I set myself a swift challenge and this helped me massively, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A Swift property that defines a custom getter and / or setter operation is a *computed property* which does not actually stores a value. The custom setter can be used to modify the internal state of other properties.

See also: "*The Swift Programming Language*" page 180

Answer (score 0):

You can not set value in its setter because you are creating a recursion -method calling itself because:

```
 self.currentShowLiked = newValue
```

will call set method you defined which will go and go. If you are overriding setter and getter you probably want to have some backing store property which will be private.

Moreover you defined a getter which base on some condition so anyway you are not using the value you set on this property. I think you do not need this set

Answer (score 0):

The code you have above will crash because it causes an infinite loop - your setter for currentShowLiked sets currentShowLiked to the new value, so then that calls the setter again, and so on.

You don't have to implement a setter, but you then don't use get - the syntax is like this:

```
   var currentShowLiked: Bool {
      return [some condition met]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error here is caused by a misunderstanding.

When you declare a

```
var a:Type
```

A member value a is allocated inside the object, and accessors and mutators are automatically created to allow you to read and write that variable.

However, when you declare

```
var a:Type { get { ... } set { ... } }
```

No member value is allocated - you have indicated that when the value is accessed (read) or mutated (written) from a user of the object, your code will do all necessary action to respond to it.  If you ultimately want the value to be stored, you will need to store it to an actual value, (which will need a different name).

Since you are invoking the mutator of the object *inside* the mutator of the object, you have set up an infinite loop, which causes your program to crash due to stack overflow (all function call memory is used to store the record of the function calling itself over and over again).